# How can I get POST request size

Tags: php, laravel, server

I am calculating request size by using following statement :

```
$request->server('CONTENT_LENGTH');
```

But on server this statement gives 0 value, so I can't able to use in validation.

Rather it doesn't consider filesize in request content length.

Comment: Should be `CONTENT_LENGTH` - last two chars transposed.

Comment: try this: https://coderwall.com/p/asjaoa/adding-a-filter-in-laravel-to-check-post-size

Comment: @SalmanZafar I tried with this also. It is working fine on my local environment, but not on server. On server it returns 0 value for CONTENT_LENGTH.